# How can I extract list of similar elements from a haskell list

Tags: haskell

Given a list such as `[1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,2,4,0,0]` and an index, how can I extract consecutive patterns of 0 in Haskell. For example if the given index is between 1 and 3 inclusive, the result is `[0,0,0]` if it is between 5 and 8 `[0,0,0,0]` and so on

Comment: If I understand correctly, you basically just need the number of zeros around the index location, correct?  The output will always be a list of N zeros?

Comment: yes, given an index I need the 0's around it

Answer (score 1):

First, build a list where run lengths are stored for each number:

```
runs :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
runs = map (head &&& length) . group
```

so e.g.

```
runs [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0] == [(1,1),(0,3),(1,1),(0,4),(1,2),(0,2)]
```

Then, index into this list by walking it in run length-sized steps:

```
indexRuns :: Int -> [(a, Int)] -> [a]
indexRuns i [] = error "Index out of bounds"
indexRuns i ((x, l):rs)
  | i < l = replicate l x
  | otherwise = indexRuns (i - l) rs
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count the number of zeros around the index

```
numZeros::Int->[Int]->Int
numZeros 0 (1:_) = 0
numZeros i (1:rest) = numZeros (i-1) rest
numZeros i theList
  | i < zeroLen = zeroLen
  | otherwise = numZeros (i-zeroLen) $ drop zeroLen theList
  where
    zeroLen = length (takeWhile (==0) theList)
```

You can replicate `0` the appropriate number of times to get the final list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in O(n) time:

```
extract :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
extract _ [] = []
extract idx (x:xs) = extract' x [x] 1 xs
  where
    extract' _ _ _ [] = [] -- Index out of bounds
    extract' v vs n (r : rest)
      | idx == n = vs ++ (takeWhile (== v) rest)
      | (v == r) = extract' v (r:vs) (n+1) rest
      | otherwise = extract' r [r] (n+1) rest
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = f' (takeWhile (== 0)) where
    f' c n    xs  | n < 0 || null xs = []
    f' c n (1:xs) = f (n - 1) xs
    f' c 0    xs  = c xs
    f' c n (0:xs) = f' ((0:) . c) (n - 1) xs
```

Or even more obfuscated

```
f n xs = g (splitAt n xs) >>= takeWhile (== 0) where
    g (xs, ys@(0:_)) = [reverse xs, ys]
    g          _     = []
```

Some tests:

```
main = mapM_ (\i -> print $ (i, f i [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])) [-1..13]
```

prints

```
(-1,[])
(0,[])
(1,[0,0,0])
(2,[0,0,0])
(3,[0,0,0])
(4,[])
(5,[0,0,0,0])
(6,[0,0,0,0])
(7,[0,0,0,0])
(8,[0,0,0,0])
(9,[])
(10,[])
(11,[0,0])
(12,[0,0])
(13,[])
```